# unable to read data from the Reader

Tags: c#, database, datareader

I am trying to display the data but from the `Reader` but is not reading it. When I debug the code using `step over / F10` it skips this line

```
trackCollection.Add(track);
```

and goes straight to this one:

```
Reader.Close();
```

Also, I added an `exception` at the end to see what's going on but it skips that too and goes to `return` and returns 0 records. Whereas the records are over 50k records.

Exception Code:

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return trackCollection;
    }
}
```

Any help as to why it's not reading data from the `reader` and how I can get it to work would be great :) thanks .

Comment: Try this : In Visual Studio, do a `Build->Clean Solution` before you debug the code again. Sometimes out of sync assemblies and PDB files can cause the IDE to skip lines of code, because it does not have the most up to date debugging symbols.

Comment: Also you can try this: In the `Test` menu item, select `Test Settings` and make sure any `.testsettings` files are unticked. A `.testsettings` file that is selected can cause havoc when stepping through code (depending on whether the test settings file has code coverage enabled for example).

Comment: @JasonEvans thanks for that - i did exactly what you suggested to do with Cleaning the solution and checking the test settings. Thanks for that, I didn't know about `.testsettings` bit but you made it clear. Though, the issue is still there and it wouldn't let me to step over in that particular line while debugging. thanks again :)

Comment: OK let's check the plug - is the project using a DEBUG or RELEASE build?

Comment: Actually, I've found many StackOverflow questions with a similar symptoms. Just Google for "visual studio debugger skipping lines" and you will see many SO hits. Hopefully one of these might help.

Comment: it's using `Debug` - thanks

Comment: ahh i C, sorry i thought maybe it might be issue with me access the `IDataReader`, I checked few on that and those answers didn't resolved my query. I hope its to do with the `debug` build. thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be 50k records in the data source, but the query you executed returns 0 of them. The code inside the `while` block is skipped because `dataReader.Read()` returns false.

Comment: thanks for that :) Could you please help on how I can over come this please?

Comment: @user3679123 You should modify the query (and/or parameter values if you use them) to return at least one record. While debugging, you could check `dbCommand.CommandText` to see if it uses the query you expected.

Comment: thanks for your help :) by removing unnecessary parameters resolved the issue. :)